# change a string into a list of select in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a string and I'm trying to separate this string into a list in a select of options.

This is what I tried :

```
render() {
        const { name, cpg, size, unit } = this.state;
        var cpglist = this.props.data.cpglist;
        var cpglist2 = cpglist.split(" ");
        let optionItems = cpglist2.map((cpg) =>
            <option key={cpg.value}>{cpg.name}</option>
        );
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <div>
                    <form>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Creer Volume</legend>
                            <label>Nom Volume : </label>
                            <select
                                name="name"
                                id="name"
                                value={name}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                            >
                                {optionItems}
                            </select>
```

Sadly this doesn't work end sends me and empty select. 
I get a warning:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

Thank you for your help

EDIT: CPGlist contains: 
SSD_r1
SSD_r5
SSD_r6
fs_cpg
CPG4S2
CPG_SYLR

Comment: with what data are you doing this since probably the 'value' > 'name' combination will not be unique for each element and thus it doesn't work

Comment: Check what cgp.value actually is. My guess is that it is undefined or the same value for every item.

Comment: SSD_r1
SSD_r5
SSD_r6
fs_cpg
CPG4S2
CPG_SYLR

this is the cpglist

Comment: Please update your post with the above sample data.

Comment: @giorgimoniava i editd. thanks didn't see. had the correct version my computer

Answer (score 1):

You use split and map not entirely correctly.

```
var cpglist = (this.props.data.cpglist).split(" ");
let optionItems = cpglist.map((cpg) =>
            <option key={cpg.value}>{cpg.name}</option>
        );
```

Even if your split works ok, it will return array of strings, e.g. `cpglist` is:

```
["1","2"]
```

Then you map it.

But inside map, you are using `cpg.value` and `cpg.name`. Each `cpg` is a string, hence they don't have `value` and `name`.

Also your `option` seems to lack value key. Here is [example](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag) how to use select properly.

Comment: so is there a way to avoid this? using for cpglist[i] maybe?

Comment: cpglist[i] is also a string, isn't it?

Comment: if I use cpglist[i]it will give me the 1st string so normally : SSD_r1. I have to do an iteration through the array or is there another way then this?

Comment: @luckysimon yes it will give you "SSD_r1" but then from this value  you need to generate key, value and inner text. Example: `<option key={cpg} value={cpg}>{cpg}</option>`. I assume cpg values are unique.

Comment: ```<option key={cpg} value={cpg}>{cpg}</option>``` I tried this but I get only 1 option with the hole string... ```SSD_r1SSD_r5SSD_r6fs_cpgCPG4S2CPG_SYLR```

Comment: @luckysimon I suggest you edit your question with this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It generated one option because probably there was one element in the array. See also the link in my updated answer

Comment: I found the issue. It wasn't a split(" ") that i needed to do but a split("\n")